# Is there a list of all alphanumeric signs in python?

Tags: python

Is there a list that contains all lower cases, upper cases, and numbers in python?

"string" does not have such a list.

Comment: The `string` module does have the (ASCII) letters and digits in two separate string constants. Surely it isn't too difficult to combine the two.

Comment: A list? Or a string?

Comment: Using `re` module is also an option for checking. There `\w` matches all alphanumeric characters (including locale-specific extensions) and the underscore.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is actually, inside `string` module

- `string.ascii_lowercase`
- `string.ascii_uppercase`
- `string.digits`
  as well as a few others

Each is given as a single string. If you want to convert them to a list, you can simply use `list(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)`

Comment: You might want to add that you can easily combine them: `list(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)`

Comment: there's also [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters)

Comment: @Graipher: yes, but not sure the whether the OP needs them as a single list.

Comment: @mata: good point

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect answer :)

Answer (score 8):

There is a `string.printable` that is a string of all printable characters. This can be made into a list as `list(string.printable)`.

If you need it, there are also:

```
whitespace -- a string containing all ASCII whitespace
ascii_lowercase -- a string containing all ASCII lowercase letters
ascii_uppercase -- a string containing all ASCII uppercase letters
ascii_letters -- a string containing all ASCII letters
digits -- a string containing all ASCII decimal digits
hexdigits -- a string containing all ASCII hexadecimal digits
octdigits -- a string containing all ASCII octal digits
punctuation -- a string containing all ASCII punctuation characters
```